# Skydrive for desktop not showing icon in notification area

Tags: notification-area, windows-8.1

NEWEST UPDATE HAS ADDED THIS FEATURE. NEW NAME: ONEDRIVE

---

is this normal behavior? I'm concerned that some files will not be transferred. For example. I need to be sure that its safe to put my laptop to sleep so that later when I'm on my desktop I wont have to open up my laptop and sync again if I closed it too early. It doesn't even appear when I THINK it is syncing.

Thanks for any help in advance.

edit 1:
Yeah I know the app isn't required or even offered anymore, but what I was wondering was if they had some way to tell if it's syncing or not. The old desktop app had an icon in the notification area which had a animation for when it was syncing, but now there isn't anything there. Although when I try to go in and make it appear it says the application isn't active and the icon will show the next time it is. Its version is 17.0.2015.0811

Is it possible to force the icon to show in the notification area if it isn't designed to show up there at all? I basically just want the same functionality of Skydrive on windows 8.

Comment: Are you sure the app is even running?

Comment: @jeruntime - The desktop application is no longer required Skydrive is not built into Windows 8.1 the syncing will happen automatically once you link your Microsoft Account.  Sadly I know of no way past that part.

Comment: Yeah I know the app isn't required or even offered anymore, but what I was wondering was if they had some way to tell if it's syncing or not. The old desktop app had an icon in the notification area which had a animation for when it was syncing, but now there isn't anything there. Although when I try to go in and make it appear it says the application isn't active and the icon will show the next time it is.
Its version is 17.0.2015.0811

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The ONEDRIVE update has fixed this issue. There is now an icon in the notification area.

Answer (score 0):

In [Windows 8.1 SkyDrive doesn't sync all files by default](http://blogs.windows.com/skydrive/b/skydrive/archive/2013/07/22/have-all-your-skydrive-files-with-you-without-using-all-your-storage-or-bandwidth.aspx). It only downloads the files that you edit or explicitly made offline. This is [called mart files](http://blogs.windows.com/skydrive/b/skydrive/archive/2013/09/30/skydrive-introduces-smart-files-in-windows-8-1.aspx)

Here is a [blog post to show the diffs](http://blogs.windows.com/windows/b/bloggingwindows/archive/2013/10/15/skydrive-and-windows-8-1.aspx) between ealier SkyDrive client and the 8.1 way.

Comment: I read that and it turns out you can right click on files in your skydrive folder and click "available offline" and THEN it downloads them.

Comment: yes, that are the new smart files. You have to make them explicitly offline.

Answer (score 0):

If you run the windows 8.1 Skydrive App (the metro/modern version) you will see in the upper right corner "uploading x items" this is how I know if any unsynced files are present on the machine I'm using. I wait for this to complete before I shut down.

Comment: the problem with this however is that it usually wont delete existing "finished" or "completed" tasks and often times will just state "pending" for everything even if everything is synced(checking via the web application).

Answer (score 0):

I also found it annoying that I couldn't see which files in my local skydrive folder were syncing with the cloud in Win 8.1

Accidently I ran into a workaround that works for me.

1. Open your webbrowser ( I used Firefox), go to skydrive.com and login.
2. Go to your mail.
3. Make a new mail.
4. Go to 'Insert' → 'Files as attachments'  (or something like that, I'm doing this in Dutch).
5. Go to the local Skydrive folder and open it.
6. The files and folders that are synced have two blue arrows in their icons. (At least, with me they have...)